# VBScript not executing sql statment properly

Tags: sql, oracle, vbscript, ora-00936

I write you this time because a VBScript that one of the application my company uses to retrieve information from an Oracle database does not seem to be working properly. Here are the facts:

1. There's part of the code that does the following:

   > ```
   > sSql = "SELECT REQ_PAYMODE" & _
   >   "  FROM SYSADM.GBPRESTATIEGROEP" & _
   >   " WHERE 1=1" & _
   >   "   AND SLEUTEL = " & sKeyPrestatiegroep 
   >
   > Set oRSGBPrest = connADO.execute(sSql)
   > If Not oRSGBPrest.EOF Then
   >   sRequestPaymodeKey = oRSGBPrest("REQ_PAYMODE")
   > Else
   >  //error handling
   > End If
   > ```
2. Using a Statement Tracer for Oracle (www.aboves.com) I can capture that same statement with its corresponding value:

   > SELECT REQ_PAYMODE FROM
   >   SYSADM.GBPRESTATIEGROEP WHERE 1=1 AND
   >   SLEUTEL = 1572499
3. Now, the VBScript is supposed to take that value and execute another query:

   > ```
   > sSql = "SELECT PAM_CODE" & _
   >           "  FROM SYSADM.PAYMODES" & _
   >           " WHERE 1=1" & _
   >           "   AND PAM_KEY = " & sRequestPaymodeKey
   >
   > Set oRSPaymodes = connADO.execute(sSql)
   > ```

Right in this last line of code, the script throws an error that says:

**ORA-00936: missing expression at line XXX --> Set oRSPaymodes = connADO.execute(sSql) <--**

Which basically means that the query in (3) is not correct, which also means that for some reason **sRequestPaymodeKey** is empty. I cannot tell this for sure because this failing sql statement does not appear in the statement tracer, but that's the only explanation I could find. However, the *worst part* is that when running the query (2) on SQLDeveloper (that's where value **sRequestPaymodeKey** comes from) it shows a row with a value other than null or zero.

I can't think of anything else that might be happening here, maybe it's just a server thing... no idea.

Any suggestions from you guys? Any way I can actually debug a VBE file?

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Can you add some logging to your vb script that writes the values of your variables to a file?

Comment: Yeah, I've done that. I put a msgbox in the first sql statement and it shows that the variable sKeyPrestatiegroep has the right value, but it's just returning no rows when executed

Comment: Something's not adding up here. If oRSGBPrest is returning no rows, you should be getting an error when you assign sRequestPaymodeKey because you're trying to access fields in an empty recordset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast sRequestPaymodeKey as a vbLong which corresponds to sql's INT.  I'm assuming PAM_KEY is an INT.  A recordset will return a string value.  So, your code would look like this:

```
If IsNumeric(sRequestPaymodeKey) Then
     sSql = "SELECT PAM_CODE" & _ 
            "  FROM SYSADM.PAYMODES" & _ 
            " WHERE 1=1" & _ 
            "   AND PAM_KEY = " & CLng(sRequestPaymodeKey)

     Set oRSPaymodes = connADO.execute(sSql)
Else
     'do error handling due to bad returned data(empty string?)
End If
```

Also, consider parameterizing your queries to prevent sql injection.

Answer (score 1):

A few ideas to try:

1. Before `Set oRSPaymodes = connADO.execute(sSql)`, put in a MsbBox and see what SQL is being executed. Is it valid? Will it run in a Oracle query analyzer(if there is one)?
2. Hard code a valid value in place of `sRequestPaymodeKey`. Does it work then?